# How to map a groupby output (list of unique values) back to the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, unique

I am having issues in mapping a groupby output back to the original dataframe. To visualize the problem i created a [test_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejwjP.png) which is assembled similar to my real dataframe:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,2,2,3,3,3], "b": ["a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "b"], "c": ["L", "O", "O", "K", "N", "O", "W"]})
```

My goal is to get all unique values of column "c" for each group (whereas a group depends on values in column a and b). I am trying to achieve this by executing:

```
test_df.groupby(["a", "b"])["c"].unique()
```

Resulting in [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNnm3.png).
I can't manage to map this back to my original "test_df". I also tried to use:

```
test_df.groupby(["a", "b"])["c"].transform(lambda x: np.unique(x))
```

Which resulted in this error: "ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 8" on my real dataframe. If I add len() around np.unique(x) it works, but it obviously doesn't return what i need.
However, my [desired DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9fyB.png) looks like this:

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,2,2,3,3,3], "b": ["a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "b"], "c": ["L", "O", "O", "K", "N", "O", "W"], "d": ["L, O", "L, O", "O", "K", "N, O, W", "N, O, W", "N, O, W"]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` is correct, but you need to wrap the output of `np.unique` as an array with same length with `x`:

```
test_df['unique_val'] = test_df.groupby(["a", "b"])["c"].transform(lambda x: [x.unique()]*len(x))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c unique_val
0  1  a  L     [L, O]
1  1  a  O     [L, O]
2  2  b  O        [O]
3  2  c  K        [K]
4  3  b  N  [N, O, W]
5  3  b  O  [N, O, W]
6  3  b  W  [N, O, W]
```

However, you seem to expect to concatenate the unique values as a single string, in which case:

```
test_df['unique_val'] = test_df.groupby(["a", "b"])["c"].transform(lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()) )
```

would work. Output:

```
   a  b  c unique_val
0  1  a  L       L, O
1  1  a  O       L, O
2  2  b  O          O
3  2  c  K          K
4  3  b  N    N, O, W
5  3  b  O    N, O, W
6  3  b  W    N, O, W
```